# How to get an embedded video to not start playing automatically

Tags: embed

I got this embed script from the View Glass website video tab:(http://viewglass.com/videos/view-dynamic-glass-intelligence/)

```
 type="text/javascript" id="vidyard_embed_code_lqsHrHITNPOc9zxsYyJVfw" src="//play.vidyard.com/lqsHrHITNPOc9zxsYyJVfw.js?v=3.1.1&type=inline&width=640&height=360"
```

And I am wondering how to stop the autoplay. Please let me know if you have any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to remove autoplay attribute from the video like this

```
$('.vjs-tech').removeAttr("autoplay");
```

or like this

```
document.getElementsByClassName('vjs-tech').removeAttribute('autoplay');
```

Use it like this

```
<p>
<script type="text/javascript" id="vidyard_embed_code_lqsHrHITNPOc9zxsYyJVfw" src="//play.vidyard.com/lqsHrHITNPOc9zxsYyJVfw.js?v=3.1.1&ty‌​‌​‌​pe=inline&width=‌​64‌​0&‌​height=360">
$(document).ready(function(){
d‌​ocum‌​ent.getElement‌​sByCla‌​ssName('vjs-‌​tech').r‌​emoveAttri‌​bute('auto‌​play');
});

<‌​/script‌​>

</‌​p>
```

Comment: Thank you for this reply and for your help.Can I simply add it in the script tab in my html :<p><script type="text/javascript" id="vidyard_embed_code_lqsHrHITNPOc9zxsYyJVfw" src="//play.vidyard.com/lqsHrHITNPOc9zxsYyJVfw.js?v=3.1.1&type=inline&width=640&height=360"></script></p>

Comment: Yes. You can do that. Let me know if that doesn't work

Comment: So I tried adding it like this : <p><script type="text/javascript" id="vidyard_embed_code_lqsHrHITNPOc9zxsYyJVfw" src="//play.vidyard.com/lqsHrHITNPOc9zxsYyJVfw.js?v=3.1.1&ty‌​pe=inline&width=640&‌​height=360"document.getElementsByClassName('vjs-tech').removeAttribute('autoplay')></script‌​></p> but it did not change anything. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: <p><script type="text/javascript" id="vidyard_embed_code_lqsHrHITNPOc9zxsYyJVfw" src="//play.vidyard.com/lqsHrHITNPOc9zxsYyJVfw.js?v=3.1.1&ty‌​‌​pe=inline&width=64‌​0&‌​height=360"docum‌​ent.getElementsByCla‌​ssName('vjs-tech').r‌​emoveAttribute('auto‌​play')></script‌​></‌​p>

Comment: Thank you for this. I tried but the video still autoplays. Should I try adding the first suggestion you made: $('.vjs-tech').removeAttr("autoplay"); at he same location?

Comment: Yes. If that doesn't work may be the iframe is loaded after javascript completes loading.

Comment: I tried it and it does not work. This is a tricky one. Thanks for all your help anyway.